# Paperclip + convert_options for thumbnail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, paperclip

My thumbnail class that are 300x300. I want to display a image in that block in a way that they don't look like it's starch.

For Example : If I upload image 500x300 or 200x600 I want to display a image proper and display background black if unnecessary white space.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Why don't you just do `{ :thumbnail => "300x300#" }`

Comment: I want to setting up "portrait" and "landscape" image